# what kind of data structure should i use to store file library..?

Tags: php, jquery, html, xml, json

I am planning to have a database of uploaded files and I was just going to put the files on my server but have a separate text-like document (json, xml, etc) that would have all the information such as name, description, tags, and school subject. I know i could use a mysql database but in reality i'd just end up sending the results to my jquery ajax call in a json through PHP's json_encode(). I feel like going ahead and just storing the name, description, and other important (quick access) info would be quicker if i already had it in xml or json format...

What would be some of the benefits of different structures for my intent?

Let me know if i wasnt very clear. I am sure i was very ambiguous.

Comment: Does the rest of your app use a database?

Comment: This is way to wide ranging - depends on many factors, most obviously what's the likely number of files you'll be uploading and what main tree structure do you have in mind? Searching files could end up being *really* slow to do compared to a quick DB search for example.

Comment: Just because XML/JSON is used as a *transport* in a *web-service* (or semi-service), doesn't mean it is a good idea to use as the *backend*.

Comment: 1) A database is used for users not for the files 2) As many files as possible, so lets say above a thousand 3) The Structure would best work as a tree hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider looking into a NoSQL database like MongoDb, DynamoDB, etc.  They are basically designed with the thought of storing schema-less data (including JSON structures) in mind.

Cases where NoSQL storage solution might be ideal include:

- The data you are trying to store does not fit into a traditional key value or relation database structure well (i.e. tree hierarchies, data is highly variable in structure, etc.)
- You need the ability to perform detailed searches/filters on the data structure.  This can be very difficult if you simply used a key value store or a relational database to store a serialized data structure.
- You need the ability to enforce read/write locks or have transactional support (i.e. items that would not be available to you with a typical flat-file data serialization approach).

Comment: @pst It adds the ability to store a document in the format he chooses (sounds like a serialized metadata in JSON might be something the OP is interested in) while still providing him database-like CRUD and lookup capabilities (so for example he wouldn't have to grep through a bunch of flat files to search for records or design his own file read-write locking mechanisms)

Comment: Thanks A lot! This is really helpful. Is there any specific one you particularly like?

Comment: @pst I didn't interpret the original question as wondering what to do about the binary files themselves, but how to store the file metadata (the separate "text-like" document). You are correct in that this sort of metadata could easily be stored in a relational DB or a NoSQL DB.  The question really becomes one of what the access patterns are for this metadata. Is the data static once written? If it gets updated, does just a portion of the metadata need to be updated or the entire metadata construct? What sort of searching does he need to allow against the metadata? These are all key questions

Comment: What would you suggest, @pst?

Comment: @pst  Your point is very valid that the original answer probably did not go into enough detail.

Comment: Well to help. The data is final. Once the file is uploaded nothing can be changed about it so that when it goes into my database (of just the metadata) that will be what is used to search when going through and once i find the appropriate file(s) say of subject Math>trigonometry>radians i display all the results getting the URL from my "text-like" database. I wouldnt actually fetch the file until they decide what they would want to download